# Call a simple web service

Tags: windows, web-services, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a web service I need to call using cmd or Powershell (so the script can be saved and scheduled) which is located at a particular URI. Simply sending a GET request to this URI will trigger the necessary task.

What is the simplest way to trigger this web service using cmd or PowerShell? (Ideally a one-liner)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PowerShell try the [`System.Net.Webclient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx) object:

```
$client = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$client.DownloadStringAsync("http://www.example.com/") | Out-Null
```

You could also do this in VBScript with an [XMLHTTPRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874):

```
Set req = CreateObject("Msxml2.XMLHttp.6.0")
req.open "GET", "http://www.example.com/", True
req.send
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in powershell / as a powershell script:

```
[System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://www.stackoverflow.com").GetResponse() | Out-Null
```

I'm not an expert on webrequest, but if it's required(or smart) to disable keep-alive for such a request, use the following:

```
$req = [System.Net.WebRequest]::CreateHttp("http://www.stackoverflow.com")
$req.KeepAlive = $false
$req.GetResponse() | Out-Null
```

Remove `Out-Null` and store the reponse if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever update to PowerShell v3, you can use the [Invoke-WebRequest](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849901.aspx) command.

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://www.stackoverflow.com
```

Comment: but he only tagged PS2.0 ^^